# Sudden downvotes by some psycho spree. How to track/find that user?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, serial-voting

All of sudden I experienced -42 total reputations down by some psycho in Stack Overflow. I know its reversible by system , but is there any way to track/find that user. Kindly provide feature to view the down-voter info too in the question or somewhere else.. my repo in SO is 3700+

Comment: why downvote??? I am asking about tracking that user

Comment: You need the diamond edition of Stack Overflow to find such users. You don't have that.

Comment: @yoda Even a diamond won't help you see who downvoted whom.  You'll need to become an SE employee, either a dev or a community manager.

Comment: @yoda Thanks, I was unware of that. As I am unable to see who voted up and who voted down with my present repo

Comment: What exactly would you do with this information?

Comment: @asawyer what exactly you do with reputations and badges?

Comment: @Servy That's not true. Not in cases like this.

Comment: @Servy: Actually, moderators do get to know suspicious patterns.

Comment: @AmitRanjan the downvotes are probably due to the tone in your question.  Mass downvotes will be detected and reversed by the SE systems

Comment: @UV-D yes it might be true, he might be frustrated of my words

Comment: Downvoting sprees are also here :)... lots of downvote in couple of mins... lolz. It seems that in a couple of hour my repo will be -ve

Comment: I can't see how it would be a good thing for you to know who is doing this. It would only invite you to try to take your revenge in some way.

Comment: @JonSkeet 10001% agree with you..

Comment: So why are you asking for that as a feature?

Comment: @JonSkeet so very true and revenge is seriously ugly

Comment: Whenever, I got a downvote, i need the reason. But most of the users just downvote and flee. They do not supply reasons, as I am getting right here .

Comment: People are downvoting your feature request because they don't agree with it.  If voting records of any kind are made public, users would start whining and backbiting rather than focusing on questions and answers. Downvoting on meta is different than on stackoverflow.  Here it merely means, "I disagree with your request" rather than "this is a bad post."

Comment: However, if you really need to see this information, it's not difficult to get.  Install a keylogger on one of the developer's computers, obtain their credentials for developer access to the DB, then use SQL to get the records you need.  Easy peasy.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/G4eoGY3.png

Comment: @AdamDavis The question is also very poorly researched; there are tons of dupes.  The "related" tab is full of them.  Clearly the OP spent no time looking for previous questions about this, nor has he brought up any new points not discussed in previous questions on the subject.  Beyond that, the question is a poorly written feature request.  It doesn't provide the compelling need for that feature, it doesn't analyze the benefits and drawbacks of implementing it, it includes unrelated information, is poorly formatted/worded, etc.  There are lots of reasons to downvote it beyond disagreement.

Answer (score 16):

> Kindly provide feature to view the down-voter info too in the question or somewhere else.

That is a bad idea that will lead to more revenge downvoting and such. You can flag one of your own posts and explain the situation, and we’ll deal with it.

The user in question has been sent a message. Yes, the system will take care of reversing the votes.
No, you don’t get to know who it was.